If you are unable to deploy the Streamlit app on the Streamlit Cloud it shows an error
I am build a project in the Streamlit framework in the Anaconda environment. I tried to deploy it on the Streamlit Cloud. So first I created the requirements.txt file using the pip install the pipreqs, and then pipreqs command, and then I pushed the app.py, requirements.txt, and can saved model in the .h5 format to GitHub. After that, I tried to deploy on the Streamlit Cloud, but it showed the error recording for the version and could not handle the data error.
github link:https://github.com/SANJAIB2004/Traffic_symbol_detector_cnn
so suggest any answer to me.
